# bash : update apt-get only if apt cache is older than 10 minutes

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying, with a script, to test if apt cache is older than 10 minutes old

```
if [ "($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Z /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp)) -ge 600000" ]; then
echo true
fi
```

But it even when the cache is 1 min old, this return true. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is not substraction ,rather you are putting a "-" symbol between two values. You can see this by trying.

```
echo "($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Z /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp))"
```

which gives in my case

```
(1403616665 - 1403583368)
```

The correct statement should be

```
echo "$[$(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Z /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp)]"
```

which correctly gives

```
33297
```

Also due to the outermost quotation marks, the statement `"($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Z /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp)) -ge 600000"` is considered as first value, which is compared to `nothing`, that's why it gives always true result.

Rounding this all up, the script would be

```
if [ "$[$(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Z /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp)]" -ge 600000 ]; then
echo true
fi
```

Comment: It resolved half the problem. I've got "60 -ge 600000" when executing `echo  ""$[$(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Z /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp)]" -ge 600000"` after 60s, but it echo `true` even with that

Comment: @Dremor Have you tried the latest version of my answer?.There were some issues with first answer.

Comment: On my ubuntu 12.04.4 I get the result in seconds, so this will return true where file < 600000 secs old (~ 1 week).  Changing it to 600 works as you would expect.